# Trying to remove a view index above child count error

Tags: react-native

What does this mean?
This happens when I update a list of iterated views something like

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
  <Ionicons name={jobIcon} color={theme.iconColor} size={30} />
  <Text>{jobService}</Text>
  <Text>{jobDate}</Text>
</View>
```

mapped inside a scrollview.

this error pops up when I modify the array from child scene.
scene1 - is where the ScrollView with job list array of views
sence2 - is where I delete a job and should update scene1 when I do remove a job

[image]

Answer (score 40):

If you want the **LayoutAnimation** to work with **ScrollView**, replace

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut)
```

with

```
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
                             duration: 300,
                             create: 
                             {
                                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
                                property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
                             },
                             update: 
                             {
                                type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
                             }
                            });
```

This works on both Android and iOS without any crashes.

Comment: Any explanation as to why this fixes the issue?

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was using LayoutAnimation for my ScrollView. Inside it a map of Items. When an Item is removed from the list this happens. Not using LayoutAnimation seems to be working fine.

Comment: Has anyone determined a work-around that does use `LayoutAnimation` and does not crash on Android?

Comment: I'm getting the same error because of LayoutAnimation on android

Answer (score 6):

It's happening when you call layout animation when it already in process. iOS will show an warning while Android will explode with this error.
You can use this easy pattern to fix it when you're using LayoutAnimation from same component.

```
layoutAnimation()  {
  if (!this.layoutAnimationActive) {
    this.layoutAnimationActive = true;
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInOut, () => { this.layoutAnimationActive = false; });
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the RN docs the `onAnimationDidEnd?` callback of `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` is only available on iOS, so I'm not sure if this solution works for Android.

Comment: I still get the error with a debounced timeout on android

Answer (score 3):

This happens when a component only has x amount of children, but you are trying to remove a child with index greater than x. Like an index out of bounds exception that is common with arrays. Can cause lots of frustration because often times the child you are trying to remove DOES INFACT EXIST. But might be happening because you are using a third party component that only expects a certain amount of children.

For me, it happened when I put an extra child into air-bnb MapView. I fixed the issue by making this element the child of it's grandparent (it was absolutely positioned so it didn't affect styling).

Comment: Hey, I have a similar issue and am using react-native-maps by airbnb.

Did you have extra children inside the main `<MapView>..</MapView>`? I tried placing a `<View>` as the child of `MapView`, so it only had a single child, but had no luck.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply - am assuming you figured this out by now. But yea, you can't put any elements as children of MapView except the ones allowed by react-native-maps. The best way to have views appear on a map is to use absolute positioning. If you need to access the map from other components, you can set the map reference as a global variable

Comment: I had no third-party dependency and it still happened. I had two absolutely positioned components with a normally positioned component between them when I got this issue. Moving the normally positioned component to be the last removed the error. It looked like react did try to remove the normally positioned component instead of the last positioned. So I guess this is a react bug.

Comment: I had the same issue when using `<MapView>`. The reason was that I put a regular `<View>` as a child component. Once it was replaced with a supported child component, the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when creating a react-native application using Expo.

This error was often getting raised when I was rendering new Markers onto a Map (which was rendered via a MapView component).

What fixed the issue for me was to add a key prop to the Marker component e.g.

```
 <Marker coordinate={coordinate} key={`${coordinate.latitude}_${coordinate.longitude}`} />
```

Hope this helps anyone who also encounters this issue when dealing with MapView and Marker components!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was deleting an item in a virtualized list. I was using redux to manage the data of the list and updated the list with the new data. However, the component for the item that was deleted caused this error.

I solved this by adding a boolean state property on this item component, example "hideItem". My item was a class component but a setState hook could also be used for a functional component. I set this to true after deletion. The post hid with layout animation correctly, and when the page refreshed it no longer rendered the deleted item. Hence, the error went away on android without needing to not use LayoutAnimation.

Comment: Hi, can you add a code snippet? It would really clearify your answer

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, it seems this bug can show its ugly face in various conditions. After a couple of hours of debugging, I found my root cause to be a key prop being passed to a component that didn't require it. I'm still unsure of why this was causing a crash, however, I suspect it has to do with the fact that the component accepts the key as a unique way to identify the view, but was *also* using the `componentWillReceiveProps(props: *)` lifecycle method that updated the component's state.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to happen if you're using some native components, where some ViewManager returns a LayoutShadowNode in createShadowNodeInstance of ViewGroupManager or something extending ReactShadowNode in createShadowNodeInstance of ViewManager on Android, and a RCTShadowView in the shadowView method of RCTViewManager on iOS. But, returns null/nil for some other View in some other ViewManager.

Then, if you combine children of both types in the same parent, and any of the elements without shadowViews/Nodes come before the changing number of elements which do have shadowViews/Nodes, then the indices won't match up, and the RCTUIManager on iOS and NativeViewHierarchyManager on Android will choke and produce these exceptions.

I solved a similar issue in react-native-svg recently, by making all the ViewManagers return values rather than null/nil. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23350

So, try upgrading react-native-svg to v9.2.4 and the issue might be fixed. Or, try moving the IonIcons to the end of your children.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, because I had an Array.map inside a condition which I was updating using LayoutAnimation.
I fixed it by moving the state variable inside the map function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vitalized flatlist with swipe left right delete option, and when list is more than 200 items and I use LayoutAnimation then the above problem comes out on arbitrary based, I figured out that deleted item still exist because of LayoutAnimation so you can play around with timings of update using the following code

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
    duration: 300,
    create: 
    {
       duration:500
       type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
       property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
    },
    update: 
    {
       duration: 500,
       type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
    }
   });
 
this.refs['task'].setNativeProps({
    style: {transform: [{translateX: Dimensions.get('window').width}]},
  });
```

one more thing, I am also hiding the item suddenly after it's deletion occurs

here is code snippet

```
this.props.handleDeleteTask(this.props.item.id);
this.setState({hideItem:true}) // here I am hiding through state function, so the item should disappear right after it's deletion.
```